# Split view controller shows only one childviewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller, uisplitview

Device iPhone 6+(support split view in landscape mode)

I am using split view controller and I have an issue in it. In portrait mode, when i print child view controllers of split view, It shows only one view controller(primary view controller). While in landscape mode, It works fine.

Can anyone help me to get the root cause.

In Portrait mode:

```
(lldb) po self.splitViewController.viewControllers
<__NSArrayI 0x7fb5ec528e70>(
<UINavigationController: 0x7fb5ec148850>
)
```

In landscape mode:

```
(lldb) po self.splitViewController.viewControllers
<__NSArrayI 0x7fc0b2eaf910>(
<UINavigationController: 0x7fc0b2a2e100>,
<UINavigationController: 0x7fc0b09b0600>
)
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This is how the `UISplitViewController` is supposed to work.

When the split view interface is expanded, this property contains two view controllers; when it is collapsed, this property contains only one view controller. The first view controller in the array is always the primary (or master) view controller. If a second view controller is present, that view controller is the secondary (or detail) view controller.

Refer https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISplitViewController_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISplitViewController/viewControllers

Comment: I agree with you. But when you create a new sample app with master detail view controller, It has two view controllers, even in portrait mode. Any clue?

Comment: iPhone 6+! device as well as simulator